# Hello everyone please help 

Tags: tape, recorder

Just a quick one i'm after a cheap tape recorder which can record faster than normal. Is anyone familiar with a device that can do this ?

Comment: How cheap do you need it to be?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean can record faster than normal? I believe you may mean can playback at a faster rate. I'm not sure of any analogue gear that can do this accurately, although I'm sure there are loads of tape players that will or can be circuit bent. Is it not something you can do digitally?

Comment: 
 I believe they means like Nagra where you can do different rates like 7.5, 15, or 30 ips - each one actually has a drastic affect upon how the sound is captured, especially for transient-natured sounds like gunshots. Something that post-recording digital time stretching can't change.  Granted, a Nagra ain't cheap, which is why the question was probably asking for something more affordable which offers similar functionality.  That's my best guess.

Comment: What I meant is if there is a tape recorder that can record at a faster speed then normal.I recall a lecture with Walter Murch who briefly mentioned this technique. Thank you Stavrosound for the insight. 

Comment: my god, are tape recorders some kind of ancient, little known devices already... ??